# How to improve multi table SELECT query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySql SELECT query which uses around 6 tables, among all 2 tables have more than 4000 records, the query I am using is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.*,
                p.name AS product,
                p.price,
                p.tax,
                l.name AS license_status,
                CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS customer,
                CONCAT(cc.firstname, ' ', cc.lastname) AS license_customer,
                cc.telephone AS license_customer_mobile
FROM order_license r
LEFT JOIN customer c ON (c.customer_id = r.customer_id)
LEFT JOIN order_product p ON (p.order_id = r.order_id
                              AND r.product_id = p.product_id)
LEFT JOIN license_status l ON (l.license_status_id = r.license_status_id)
LEFT JOIN customer cc ON (cc.customer_id = r.license_customer_id)
WHERE r.license_status_id = '7'
  AND r.validity > 0
ORDER BY r.end_date ASC LIMIT 0,10
```

The problem is its taking around 1 min to show records, which is very high for such a low number of records. MySql server is a Linode VPS which is fairly fast as well. Now I have no idea whats going wrong.

I have tried to add indexes and removed LEFT JOINS (as given in query below) but result are almost same.

```
SELECT r.*,
       p.name AS product,
       p.price,
       p.tax,
       l.name AS license_status,
       CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS customer,
       CONCAT(cc.firstname, ' ', cc.lastname) AS license_customer,
       cc.telephone AS license_customer_mobile
FROM order_license r,
     order_product p,
     license_status l,
     customer c,
     customer cc
WHERE (p.order_id = r.order_id
       AND r.product_id = p.product_id)
  AND (l.license_status_id = r.license_status_id)
  AND (c.customer_id = r.customer_id)
  AND (cc.customer_id = r.license_customer_id)
  AND r.license_status_id = '7'
  AND r.validity > 0
ORDER BY r.end_date ASC LIMIT 0,10
```

Please help.

Comment: You know the _magic power_ of [SELECT EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html)?

Comment: The first query uses unnecessary left joins, and repeats each join condition in the `WHERE`. The second is even worse. Without a join condition, you're getting a Cartesian product of every row in all of those tables, which only gets filtered in the `WHERE`.

Comment: Can you give me the info of ur order_license?
what is the primary key of that table?

Comment: I am so sorry all, by mistake I had added unwanted code after WHERE. Now corrected.

Comment: The primary key for order_license id order_license_id

Comment: I have removed JOIN with order_product table which ad too many records and now query works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you are overwriting the `ON` conditions in your `WHERE` clause.

change that :

```
WHERE (p.order_id = r.order_id
   AND r.product_id = p.product_id)
AND (l.license_status_id = r.license_status_id)
AND (cc.customer_id = r.license_customer_id)
AND r.license_status_id = '7'
AND r.validity > 0
ORDER BY r.end_date ASC LIMIT 0,10
```

to

```
WHERE  r.license_status_id = '7' 
AND r.validity > 0 
ORDER BY r.end_date ASC LIMIT 0,10
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this code? reply ASAP if not helping

```
SELECT
  R.*,
  P.name  AS product,
  P.price,
  P.tax,
  L.name  AS license_status,
  CONCAT( C.firstname, ' ', C.lastname) AS customer
  CONCAT( CC.firstname, ' ', CC.lastname) AS license_customer
  CC.telephone AS license_customer_mobile
FROM order_license R
  LEFT JOIN customer C
    ON C.customer_id = R.customer_id
  LEFT JOIN order_product P
    ON P.order_id = R.order_id
      AND P.product_id = R.product_id
  LEFT JOIN license_status L
    ON L.license_status_id = R.license_status_id
  LEFT JOIN customer CC
    ON CC.customer_id = R.customer_id
WHERE R.validity > 0
    AND R.license_status_id = 7 
GROUP BY R.order_license_id
ORDER BY R.end_date LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but time taken is almost same as mine.